# Loading triplet formatted data in pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I have a csv file in the following format:

```
email       Peter    peter@example.com
id          Peter    23
age         John     31
fullname    John     John Smith
id          John     25
```

i.e., the first field is the key name, the second the index value and the third the data value. I do not have the list of all key names in front however.

What would be the most efficient way to create a DataFrame object out of this data?

**Update**: The format allows for missing data, i.e John's email in this case is a NaN.

Comment: Your data is a little messed up, do you want `NaN` values for missing column values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on how you want to have the final dataframe, you can use `pivot` for this:

```
In [1]: s = """email       Peter    peter@example.com
   ...: id          Peter    23
   ...: age         John     31
   ...: fullname    John     John Smith
   ...: id          John     25"""

In [4]: df = pd.read_fwf(StringIO(s), names=["key", "name", "value"])

In [5]: df
Out[5]:
        key   name              value
0     email  Peter  peter@example.com
1        id  Peter                 23
2       age   John                 31
3  fullname   John         John Smith
4        id   John                 25

In [6]: df.pivot(index='name', columns='key', values='value')
Out[6]:
key    age              email    fullname  id
name
John    31                NaN  John Smith  25
Peter  NaN  peter@example.com         NaN  23
```

Comment: this is so great it certainly falls into the category "what haven't i thought of this" :)